How can one determine whether a room's booking will be automatically accepted/declined, or chosen by delegates?
Using the MS Graph API, I have retrieved the list of rooms. Some rooms automatically accept/reject bookings, while others require selection by a representative. How can this be distinguished?

I tried searching for information in the rooms and users information but couldn't find any way

You can't access the calendar booking policies using the Graph, they are held in a FAI (folder associated item) in the calendar folder but unfortunately graph doesn't give you access to these type of item either. You can get that information programmatically via the admin cmdlet's https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/exchange/get-calendarprocessing?view=exchange-ps which are backed buy a yet unsupported REST API https://outlook.office.com/adminApi
